# Tooltip is not working inside the List properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I need to show a Tooltip on the buttons present in the lists. In the picture below, you can see a group of buttons (which will be manipulated as the data comes from the DB on each and every time).

But the problem is, in the below picture you can see the button in the lists shows the Tooltip only on the buttons present in the first row, while hovering on the buttons from second row the Tooltip doesn't show the tip.

I want to show the Tooltip for all the buttons. Can anyone tell what I did wrong in this? I've added my code below the picture.

[image]

```
{
  Object.keys(chitties).map((key, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td>{index + 1}</td>
        <td>{chitties[key].chittyName}</td>
        <td>{moment(chitties[key].startDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}</td>
        <td>{chitties[key].psoId}</td>
        <td>{chitties[key].auctionDay}</td>
        <td>{chitties[key].totalMonth}</td>
        <td>{numberFormat(chitties[key].totalAmount)}</td>
        <td>
          <Link
            to={`/chitties/list/${this.props.match.params.id}/detail/${key}`}
          >
            <Button
              color="primary"
              className="btn-pill"
              id="UncontrolledTooltipExample"
            >
              <i className="fa fa-eye" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip
              placement="top"
              target="UncontrolledTooltipExample"
            >
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link to={`/chitties/list/${this.props.match.params.id}/edit/${key}`}>
            <Button
              color="secondry"
              className="btn-pill"
              id="UncontrolledTooltip"
            >
              <i className="fa fa-pencil" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target="UncontrolledTooltip">
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link to={`/chitties/${key}/addUser`}>
            <Button
              color="success"
              className="btn-pill"
              id="UncontrolledToolti"
            >
              <i className="fa fa-user-plus" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target="UncontrolledToolti">
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link to={`/chitties/${this.props.match.params.id}/auction/${key}`}>
            <Button color="danger" className="btn-pill" id="UncontrolledTool">
              <i className="fa fa-calendar-plus-o" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target="UncontrolledTool">
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link
            to={`/chitties/${this.props.match.params.id}/paymentList/${key}`}
          >
            <Button color="warning" className="btn-pill" id="Uncontrolle">
              <i className="fa fa-inr" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip placement="down" target="Uncontrolle">
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the IDs used for triggering the popup are not unique when you map over the list of items.

You can solve this by adding the `key` that you are using to the IDs mentioned:

```
<Button
  color="primary"
  className="btn-pill"
  id={`tooltip1-${key}`}
>
 <i className="fa fa-eye" />
</Button>
<UncontrolledTooltip
  placement="top"
  target={`tooltip1-${key}`}
 >
```

Full Code:

```
{
  Object.keys(chitties).map((key, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td>{index + 1}</td>
        <td>{chitties[key].chittyName}</td>
        <td>{moment(chitties[key].startDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}</td>
        <td>{chitties[key].psoId}</td>
        <td>{chitties[key].auctionDay}</td>
        <td>{chitties[key].totalMonth}</td>
        <td>{numberFormat(chitties[key].totalAmount)}</td>
        <td>
          <Link
            to={`/chitties/list/${this.props.match.params.id}/detail/${key}`}
          >
            <Button
              color="primary"
              className="btn-pill"
              id={`tooltip1-${key}`}
            >
              <i className="fa fa-eye" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip
              placement="top"
              target={`tooltip1-${key}`}
            >
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link to={`/chitties/list/${this.props.match.params.id}/edit/${key}`}>
            <Button
              color="secondry"
              className="btn-pill"
              id={`tooltip2-${key}`}
            >
              <i className="fa fa-pencil" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target={`tooltip2-${key}`}>
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link to={`/chitties/${key}/addUser`}>
            <Button
              color="success"
              className="btn-pill"
              id={`tooltip3-${key}`}
            >
              <i className="fa fa-user-plus" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target={`tooltip3-${key}`}>
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link to={`/chitties/${this.props.match.params.id}/auction/${key}`}>
            <Button color="danger" className="btn-pill" id={`tooltip4-${key}`}>
              <i className="fa fa-calendar-plus-o" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target={`tooltip4-${key}`}>
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link
            to={`/chitties/${this.props.match.params.id}/paymentList/${key}`}
          >
            <Button color="warning" className="btn-pill" id="Uncontrolle">
              <i className="fa fa-inr" />
            </Button>
            <UncontrolledTooltip placement="down" target="Uncontrolle">
              Hello world!
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
          </Link>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```